# Unit testing in Golang for Http Client inside a Handler

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a handler that is making another call to a http client. I am not sure how to
create a unit test for this handler. I have tried some methods of mocking the http client
but it gave me lots of issues. I do not wish to use dependency injection because my HandlerFunc
expects a type `func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request)`
Does anyone know how I can perform unit testing on this?

```golang
func ReadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // retrieve url link from the url query params
    link := r.URL.Query().Get("foo")

    // making a call to http client to get the response
    req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(context.Background(), http.MethodGet, link, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    client := &http.Client{}
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    log.Println(res.Body)
    
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have resolved the issue by moving the `http.NewRequestWithContext` to another function and unit test that separately. This helped because of the separation of concerns.

Comment: Use net/http/httptest to start up a Server with a fake handler, make the actual call. Dead simple. Stop mocking, test actual code.

Comment: As @Volker mentioned use the https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest module to create a `NewRecorder`. This way you can test your handler.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use dependency injection.

Comment: These videos may help:  [HTTP client testing](https://youtu.be/ebEfF1wzc54?si=nQtt0ut_oLjEYnms), [HTTP server testing](https://youtu.be/tCAl8fdqDnM?si=R8F2KAqaizdT2Zhw).